# ggplot function select multiple subset

Tags: r, subset, ggplot2

I'm not an expert with the ggplot2 package. I have a subset selection problem.

Here is my code that produce this kind of graph...

```
  g <- ggplot(merged_data,aes_string(x=Order,fill=var.y)) + 
               scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.05,0)) + 
              xlab(paste("Order","Total number of sequences",sep=" - ")) + 
              ggtitle(main.str) +
              geom_bar(position="fill", 
                       subset = .(Order !=  ""), 
                       width=0.6,hjust =0)+
              geom_text(stat="bin",  
                        subset = .(Order !=  ""), 
                        color="black", hjust=1, vjust = 0.5, size=2,
              aes_string(fill=NULL,x = Order,y = "0", label="..count.."))+
              coord_flip()
```

For `geom_bar` and `geom_text`  I select subset of data that remove empty names

```
subset = .(eval(parse(text=var.x)) !=  "")
```

this is a simple example with only 2 bars.
Here is a the data ...

```
Collector<- c("BK","YE_LD","BK","JB","JB",
         "BK","BK","BK","JB","YE_LD")
Order<-c("A","B","B","B","A",
         "B","B","A","B","B")
data <- data.frame(Order,Collector)
```

[image]

Now I want to add a cutoff to my subset... only show the variable that that have a minimum of counts.

So if I put the cutoff = 4 ... I will get only the bar at the bottom that have 7 counts, the bar at the top with 3 counts should not appear.

I have no idea how I can do this ...
Thanks for your help.

Comment: could you provide some sample data ?

Comment: Furthermore, I'd suggest making your example a little more minimal. Much of the titling, axis labelling and other theming distracts from the actual problem.

Comment: You need more to make this a reproducible example. Where is `var.y` and `main.str`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a subset of the data and use this new object in `ggplot`. The following command will remove all `Order` conditions with less than four data points:

```
subset(data, Order %in% names(which(table(Order) >= 4)))


   Order Collector
2      B     YE_LD
3      B        BK
4      B        JB
6      B        BK
7      B        BK
9      B        JB
10     B     YE_LD
```